# Prestashop stopped redirecting to any page without any change in configuration

Tags: url, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have prestashop 1.6.1.22 connected to my domain (for example [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com)). I did not make any change for the last couple of days in my website configuration. Today I cannot connect to any page. Google Chrome shows ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT. When connecting to admin dashboard i see

> "You are connected to domain [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com). This is a different value
> than the main domain of the store set in "SEO & URL". If you make your
> domain, please change it now."

When I click "Change it now" it redirects me to URL & SEO settings but there is nothing under "SET SHOP URL". However when I looked into database I see correct values under PS_SHOP_DOMAIN and PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL. Any idea what happend and when to look for an error?

Answer (score 0):

So you checked the values in the configuration table, did you also check the `domain` and the `domain_ssl` in the shop_url table?
And maybe set the debug true in the `config/defines.inc.php` to see if there are any error messages.

Comment: Yes, the 'domain' and 'domain_ssl' values are correct. (www.mysite.com in both cases). I did turn the debug on in 'defines.inc.php' but it doesn't really make any difference- when refreshing it shows the same message. (on Mozilla Firefox it shows 302 code) I'm starting to think my hosting provider did something that started the problem.

Comment: well, not that this is the issue but in the shop_url, the values of the domain and domain_ssl has to be domain.com not www.domain.com and the physical_uri set to "/" if the files are in the web server's root.

Comment: Good point, I've just changed the values to mysite.com, but it didn't fix anything. Physical_uri is "/" even though my site files are in "/folder" because in hosting settings mysite.com points at "/folder" already.

Comment: you could do a simple test to see if really the hosting setting works. Write a test.html file in this /folder to display a generic message like "Testing...." and then in browser go to www.example.com/test.html to verify the test message displays. If it does then indeed is a problem with your PS install. Are you running Apache or Nginx?

Comment: I don't really know whether it is Apache or Nginx, it's completely on hosting provider site. The test.html file opens just fine.

Comment: When trying to open my site with Firefox it shows following error:The site at has experienced a network protocol violation that cannot be repaired. The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because an error in the data transmission was detected. Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.

Comment: Sometimes even in admin panel it shows ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT out of the sudden. Strange.

Comment: I think someone broke into my admin panel. I had recovered backup from 3 days before the problem and it works. Need to check out the logs and I'm already seeing some weird stuff.